# How to display standardized y-scores in interaction plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a two-way interaction of standardized data in R using the package "interplot". However, the displayed y-scores are not standardized anymore. Why is that and how can I fix that?

I have tried to change the y-limits and to use the "scale_y_continuous()" function.

```
# generate data
x <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
y <- x + rnorm(100, 0, 1)
z <- y + rnorm(100, 0, 1)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,z)) 

# build model with interaction term
model1 <- glm(y ~ x*z, data=df)

# plot interaction
require(interplot)
interplot(model1, var1 = "x",var2 = "z", ci = 0.95, predPro = TRUE,
    var2_vals = c(-1, 1), hist=F) + xlim(-3, 3) +
    theme_classic()
```

I expect the y-scale to display values between -3 and +3, since the scores are standardized. However, the displayed y-values are between 20 and 80.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of `?interplot` example :

```r
set.seed(123)
# generate data
x <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
y <- x + rnorm(100, 0, 1)
z <- y + rnorm(100, 0, 1)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))

# build model with interaction term
model1 <- glm(y ~ x*z, data=df)
# lm(y ~ x*z, data=df) # glm => is a linear model

# plot interaction
require(interplot, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
interplot(model1, var1 = "x",var2 = "z", ci = 0.95,
          predPro = TRUE, var2_vals = c(-1,1)) +
        xlim(-3, 3) +
        xlab("x values") +
        ylab("Estimated Coefficient for z") +
        ggtitle('Estimated Coefficient of z by x conditionally to y in c(-1,1)') +
        theme_classic()
```

[image]

```r
interplot(model1, var1 = "x",var2 = "z", ci = 0.95) +
        xlim(-3, 3) +
        xlab("x values") +
        ylab("Estimated Coefficient for z") +
        ggtitle('Estimated Coefficient of z by x') +
        theme_classic()
#> Warning: Removed 28 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]